# Kernel panic - not synching: Attempted to kill init

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

After updating vscode, glibc and stdlibc++ was asked to be updated, however when I am trying to take this operation, an error occurred: no matter which command I use(e.g. ls, pwd), I get the same output: ...relocation...(Forgot the detailed content). I try to reboot ubuntu but I failed.

[image]

I tried the methods forum providing but it didn't work, please help me with this, thank you

Comment: Your BIOS may need an upgrade. Please search online for a BIOS upgrade for your particular machine. Also, in your question please specify what Ubuntu version you are running.